# Get activities of a Google plus user using Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-plus

I am trying to read and display activities of a G+ user. Using **Google oauth2** I could able to recieve the access_token of a user after authorization has completed.

I use **google_plus** gem to make calls to G+, i could able to recieve user information using below code

`@person = GooglePlus::Person.get("user_id_goes_here", :key => "google_api_key_here")`

but when i try to get the activities using below

`activity = GooglePlus::Activity.get("user_id_goes_here")`

i could able to see the below error,

[image]

i tried searching the web for a solution, and some suggest that the api call limit exceeded. (10,000 hits/day is default). But i am sure i have used this only with 20-30 calls today.

Any suggestions for this issue is appreciated.

**FYI :** I have just added config code for google_oauth2 in /config/initializers/omniauth.rb file as below `provider :google_oauth2,Rails.application.config.client_id , Rails.application.config.client_secret`

**Note:** Below is the screenshot when i try to authenticate with Oauth2.
I hope this doesnot include Google plus scope, to make it i know i should add {:scope => "REQUIRED_URL_HERE_GOOGLE_PLUS_RELATED"} in omniauth.rb. But not sure what url should i give in there.

[image]

Thanks,
Balan

Comment: if you are running rspec tests or similar, and haven't stubbed this method, you may have run this more times then you think. I don't know what your code looks like, so this may not be relevant in your case, but worth thinking about.

Comment: if you need any more information about my code to give a suggestion for this issue. Please let me know.

Comment: could you confirm (1) fetching user info always works? (2) fetching activities never works, even after 24hrs for your API limit to reset?

Comment: having looked through the gem specs, looks like you need to pass your Google API key to the `Activity` method, in the same way you have passed it to the `Person` method. The examples in the docs where this is omitted assume you have defined `GooglePlus.api_key = 'your key'` in your config somewhere. Not sure if you have, but you should check.

Comment: I have updated the question.. please have a look

Comment: API endpoints are listed here: https://developers.google.com/gdata/faq#AuthScopes. So is your limit issue resolved?

Comment: wohoo... i got it working i used {:scope => "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me"}, and could able to see the feeds..

Thanks for your suggestions Andy..

Comment: Andy i appreciate your response for this question.. 
As i could not +1 you for this question, i have +1ed you for one of your best question..

Comment: looks like my comments above were the answer you needed, no?

Comment: Not actually.. I found it myself..
+1 for your effort to answer..

Comment: really? your original question was due to the api key being ommitted. Which is exactly the answer I gave you. And I don't believe you have +1 any of my comments

Comment: i +1 your another question, before you actually put answer for my question here.. and you posted your answer right after i post my answer.

Comment: thanks balanv, glad you got your issue sorted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Google_Plus gem requires you to pass your app key with every request. You can either do this inline:

```
GooglePlus::Activity.get("user_id_goes_here", key: "api_key_goes_here")
```

Or set up a global variable in an initializer

```
GooglePlus.api_key = 'api_key_goes_here'
```

The examples in the gem spec assume you have included a global variable, and hence don't show the `key:` strings. This may be what is causing you problems?

In answer to your second question, you will need to specify a scope with your oauth requests. A list of scopes is given here https://developers.google.com/gdata/faq#AuthScopes, but it is worth noting that the url format seems to have changed from that published. Try `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/xxxxx` instead, where xxx is the service you require.

Answer (score 0):

I could able to find a solution for my question..

```
1) Used {:scope => "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me"} in /config/initializers/omniauth.rb file
2) Used the code 

    activities = GooglePlus::Activity.for_person("user_id", :key => "GOOGLE_API_KEY").items
```

Hope someone will find this useful.